# minlength attribute doesn't seem to be working

Tags: html, input

Say I have the following HTML:

```
<form>
    Fax #: <input type="number" name="fax" minlength="10" required />
    <button>Print</button>
</form>
```

If I enter in "11" as the Fax # and hit "Print" the form submits without issue. I would like it to present some sort of error. If the minlength attribute doesn't do that then what exactly does the minlength attribute do?

I'm using Google Chrome 74..

Comment: Did you see this page first? I guess your target browser doesn't fall on the preferred 'side of the line'. https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-minlength

Comment: does this work in your browser? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-minlength

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `minlength` attribute doesn't apply for `input` of type `number`. This is actually quite reasonable. Numbers don't have a length, text do. For reference, see [The official documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#apply).

Using `input type="number"` for a fax field is semantically incorrect, anyway. You should use `input type="text"`. Then you can limit its length by the `maxlength` or `minlength` attributes or even use the `pattern` one.

If you absolutely need to use `number` as input type and you need to limit the value to 10 digits, you can do it by using `min` and `max` attributes:

```
Fax #: <input type="number" name="fax" min="1000000000" max="9999999999" required />
```

Like I said, though, this is absolutely incorrect semantically.